# Facebook Request Dialog Working in Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer

I am trying to share my Facebook Canvas app and for some reason the request dialog works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. Here is my code:

```
FB.init({
            appId: 'MyAPPID',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            oauth: true  
        });

function inviteFriends() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'MY MESSAGE',
        title:'MY TITLE'
      }, requestCallback);
}
function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
 }
```

As it is only not working in IE i would assume it to be a formatting problem but it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a cookie and/or P3P issue with IE.  To fix the P3P issue, you will need to add a p3p header to each response from the webserver.  See:

http://evolt.org/node/20756

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3285406.htm

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx

Comment: After alot of investigation sadly this hasn't fixed the issue. The app still reads the same error. However i have found that I do get the error "Invalid Argument - Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." only in IE though.